# What is the relation between Number.prototype.toLocaleString() and Intl.NumberFormat.prototype.format?

Tags: javascript, localization, number-formatting, ecmascript-intl

We are trying to use localization support in our application and looking at the `toLocaleString()`. We also had a look at `Intl.NumberFormat` and its format method.

Do they have any relation? Which one is better to use?

Comment: Thank you for replying back. yes, I read both of them and I can see that via both ways I can achieve almost similar tasks. However, I am still trying to find which one is better than other (in other words, which one I should prefer and why). I also saw a minimal reference of Intl namespace in localeString doc, but didn't quite grasp how they are related. So, looking for some real world examples.

Answer (score 16):

From MDN docs for [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

> #### Performance:
>
> When formatting large numbers of numbers, it is better to create a `NumberFormat` object and use the function provided by its `NumberFormat.format` property.

In most cases you can use `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`. It's simpler to use, because it allows you to format a number using one function call. `Intl.NumberFormat` is useful only when you want to format a large amount of numbers.

Comment: `Intl.NumberFormat` is also useful when you need to pass a formatter function, such as when the format is determined at **run-time** based on a configuration file or user input.